# c# mvc model binding nested lists

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, modelbinder

I got a problem with my model binding.
Got here following models:

```
public class RoomScan
{
    public RoomScan() { }

    public RoomScan(Guid id)
    {
        Room_ID = id;
        Assets = new List<AssetScanModel>();
    }
    //public Guid Soll_ID { get; set; }
    public Guid Room_ID { get; set; }
    public List<AssetScanModel> Assets { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Barcode", ResourceType = typeof(Dictionary))]
    public string Barcode { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "RFID", ResourceType = typeof(Dictionary))]
    public string RFID { get; set; }
}

public class AssetScanModel
{
    public AssetScanModel(Asset asset)
    {
        Asset = asset;
        Scanned = false;
        CheckIn = false;
    }

    public Asset Asset { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Scanned", ResourceType = typeof(Dictionary))]
    public bool Scanned { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "CheckIn", ResourceType = typeof(Dictionary))]
    public bool CheckIn { get; set; }
}
```

The View does list all the Assets:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Scan", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post))
{
Html.HiddenFor(rs => rs.Room_ID);
Html.HiddenFor(rs => rs.Assets);

<div>
    <div class="editor-label">Barcode</div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input type="text" name="Barcode" value="@Model.Barcode" /></div>
</div>
<div>
    <div class="editor-label">RFID</div>
    <div class="editor-field"><input type="text" name="Barcode" value="@Model.RFID" /></div>
</div><br />
```

...

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Assets.Count; i++)
{
    <tr>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Assets[i].Asset.InventoryNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Assets[i].Asset.Description)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Assets[i].Asset.Manufacturer)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Assets[i].Asset.Model)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Assets[i].Asset.SerialNumber)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Assets[i].Scanned)</td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Assets[i].CheckIn)</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I added the "Asset[i]" because I read somewhere it helps the default model binder to bind propperly (didn#t work)

My problem is: in my controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Scan(RoomScan toVerify)
```

the List is empty (not null).
I know this has to do with the model binder, but I am not familiar how to change it so it does work.

Comment: first change the DisplayFor to EditorFor ... then look at the generated html. Next make sure the input names look like toVerify.Assests[0].Assest.Inventory etc.

Comment: You should be using `public ActionResult Scan(IEnumerable<RoomScan> toVerify){}`. Please check [this](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx)

Comment: @DavidPerlman I am just displaying the List, there should be no edit fields. the whole list is part of a form, in wich you can send a RFID or Barcode to the controller. Wich checks a scanned asset and sets "scanned" = true
Also, the RoomScan Model is no List, it just contains one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been using this for binding complex models with nested lists.  I almost always replace the default model binder with this right off the bat...

[A DefaultModelBinder that can update complex model graphs](http://www.codetuning.net/blog/post.aspx?id=1cf10893-3ec8-4af5-9bf8-fc6065673a29)

I hope this helps you as much as it did me.

Comment: Looks like the right direction.
I implemented it, but in the controller the AssetScanModel List is null.. I checked the new modelBinder, and he does not even get a AssetScanModel List from the view. Thats wierd, I think there is a big blunder i coded in

Comment: found some mistakes on my side in the view (it seems html helper tend to be ignored if they are not wrapped around a html tag (div, etc)

Comment: Ah, yes.  That'll get ya.  Glad you were able to get it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

Try DisplayTemplates/EditorTemplates, create template for ur nested model type.
In View write:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Assets)
```

in DisplayTemplate (AssetScanModel.cshtml):

```
@model AssetScanModel

<tr>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Asset.InventoryNumber)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Asset.Description)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Asset.Manufacturer)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Asset.Model)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Asset.SerialNumber)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.Scanned)</td>
    <td>@Html.DisplayFor(asm => asm.CheckIn)</td>
</tr>
```